# How to connect to Wireless Wifi with 13.04?

Tags: wireless, 13.04, connection

Just installed Ubuntu 13.04 64bit, trying to connect to a wireless wifi receiver I have in my house. Not showing up in networks? Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Click on network icon (on top bar of Ubuntu ) than select network settings .

Now you can choose wireless option from your network manager.

And if there is problem in enabling your WiFi use following command.

```
$ sudo rfkill unblock all
```